# Why does my cs50 sepia filter not compute the right pixel values?

Tags: cs50

for some reason the math portion of my sepia code does not seem to work.  I get errors when I run check50, and it shows all the pixel values as being too high.  I triple check the values for the filter but all seems good.

```
    void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
 float org_red = 0;
 float org_green = 0;
 float org_blue = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            org_red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            org_green = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            org_blue = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;

            long sepiaRed = (.393 * org_red + .769 * org_green + .189 * org_blue);
            long sepiaGreen = (.349 * org_red) + .686 * org_green + .168 * org_blue;
            long sepiaBlue = (.272 * org_red + .534 * org_green + .131 * org_blue);


            if (sepiaRed > 255)
            {
                sepiaRed = 255;
            }

            if (sepiaGreen > 255)
            {
                sepiaGreen = 255;
            }

            if (sepiaBlue > 255)
            {
                sepiaBlue = 255;
            }

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sepiaRed);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sepiaGreen);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sepiaBlue);
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

The error i get says

:( sepia correctly filters single pixel
expected "56 50 39\n", not "84 75 58\n"
:( sepia correctly filters simple 3x3 image
expected "100 89 69\n100...", not "100 88 69\n100..."
:( sepia correctly filters more complex 3x3 image
expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "30 27 21\n71 6..."
:( sepia correctly filters 4x4 image
expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "30 27 21\n71 6..."